# Reading a FILE and using fscanf goes into an infinite loop

Tags: c

Here is the function that is given a FILE to scan:

```
void scan(FILE *file) {

    while (true) {
        char s1[1001];
        int result = fscanf(file, "%10s", s1);
        printf("%d\n", result);
        s1[1001] = '\0';
        if (result == EOF) break;
    }


}
```

I use fopen on file before passing it to this function.
It prints out -1 in an infinite loop, but it doesn't break. How come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on what is `s1`.

Make sure its a `char s1[ appropriate_size ]` and not `char * s1`.

Its working great in my case:
[image: Test]

Comment: Shouldn't this `s1[1001] = '\0';` be `s1[1000] = '\0';`?

Comment: So, my goal was to separate the main and a separate function that processes the tokens that are scanned inside of the file. It works when the fopen is located in the same function as the fscanf. My problem is that when I try to fopen the file in the main, then send the FILE to a different function, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hello, the problem was setting the last character to be '\0'

Answer (score 2):

You have an off-by-one error when forcing the null terminator in `s1`, this:

```
s1[1001] = '\0';
```

runs past the end of `s1`, it should be:

```
s1[1000] = '\0';
```

When you declare an array in C as `char s1[X];`, the `X` is the number of elements in the array and since C arrays are indexed starting from zero, the last element is `s1[X-1]`.

This off-by-one could be changing the value of `result` between the `printf` and the `result == EOF` check.